# How to hide header, sidebar and just display what is in my layout? without loading theme

Tags: layout, theme

I have mywallet.phtml. I only want to display the data inside this custom layout without loading header, footer, side bar etc.

```
<?php

$idruleparam=$this->getRequest()->getParam('idrule');

$ruleparam = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule')->load($idruleparam);


$isPartner= Mage::getModel('marketplace/userprofile')->isPartner();
$customerid=Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
$helper=Mage::helper('socialcoupon');
if($isPartner==1){

$couponrulescoll = Mage::getModel('socialcoupon/socialCouponRules')->getCollection()
            ->addFieldToFilter('mageuserid', $customerid);
?>

    <div class="page-title">
            <h1><?php echo $helper->__('MY wallet') ?></h1>
    </div>


<div class="fieldset">
    <h2 class="legend"><?php echo $helper->__('Wallet') ?></h2>

    <div class="wk_content">
    <?php  
        if ($couponrulescoll->count() == 0) {
            echo $helper->__("Please like to get coupon");
        } else { ?>
        <div class="head">          
            <span class="label">
                <?php echo $helper->__('Coupon Code')?>
            </span>
            <span class="label">
                <?php echo $helper->__('Discount')?>
            </span>
            <span class="label">
                <?php echo $helper->__('Coupon Left')?>
            </span>                     

            <span class="label">
                <?php echo $helper->__('Days Remaining')?>
            </span>
             <span class="label">
                                    <?php echo $helper->__('Sku')?>
                            </span>
             <span class="label">
                                    <?php echo $helper->__('Product Name')?>
                            </span>     
                <span>



        </div>



        <div class="wk_clear"></div>
        <div class="wk_seller_product">

            <?php
                                foreach($couponrulescoll as $scrule){
                    //var_dump($scrule);
                    //echo "Mage rule id ".$scrule->getMageruleid()."<br>";
                    $rule = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule')->load($scrule->getMageruleid());


                    foreach ($rule->getCoupons() as $coupon) {
                        //var_dump($coupon);
                        $couponcode = $coupon->getCode();
                        $couponid = $coupon->getId();
                        //$id=$products->getId();                           
                        //echo "$couponcode <br>";
                    if ($rule->getDiscountAmount() != "")
                        {
                            ?>
                <div class="wk_row_view">
                    <input type="hidden" class="hidden_id" value="<?php echo $rule->getRuleId(); ?>" />
                    <span class="label"><?php echo $couponcode; ?></span>
                    <span class="label"><?php echo $rule->getDiscountAmount(); ?></span>
                    <span class="label"><?php echo $rule->getUsesPerCoupon(); ?></span>


                    <span class="label"><?php   
                                                $currentTimestamp = Mage::getModel('core/date')->timestamp(time());
                                                $currentDate = date('Y-m-d', $currentTimestamp);
                                             $futuredate=$rule->getToDate();



                                       $timeremaining = abs(strtotime($futuredate) - strtotime($currentDate)); 
                                        echo floor($timeremaining/(60*60*24)); 
                                          ?> </span>
                    <span class="label"><?php 
                        $substr3 =  $rule->getCouponProducts();
                        /*foreach ($rule->getCoupons() as $coupon2) {
                            echo "test".  $coupon2->getCode(); 
                        }*/
                        echo $substr3; 
                    ?></span>
                <span class="label"><?php

                        $productNames = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('sku', $substr3);

                        foreach ($productNames as $productName) {
                        $product2=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productName->getId());
                            echo  $product2->getName();
                            }
                                            ?></span>

                </div>
                <?php } ?>
                <div class="wk_clear"></div>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
    <?php }} ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your Module

```
app/code/local/Namespace/Module/
```

Create a config.xml in an `etc/` folder:

```
app/code/local/Namespace/Module/etc/config.xml
```

In config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <wallet>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Namespace_Module</module>
                    <frontName>wallet</frontName>
                </args>
            </wallet>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Create a controller in the `controllers/` folder:

```
app/code/local/Namespace/Module/controllers/IndexController.php
```

Here is the controller.  Please note the `loadLayout()` method passes the argument `false`.  If false is passed, the `default` handle, (which holds header, footer, etc.) will not be loaded.

```
class Namespace_Module_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {

    public function indexAction() {
        $this->loadLayout(false);
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

Now in your layout.xml.  Since this is a top level node, you have to specify `output="toHtml"`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <namespace_wallet_wallet>
        <block type="core/template" template="path/to/wallet.phtml" output="toHtml" />
    </namespace_wallet_wallet>
</layout>
```

Now when you go to http://yourdomain.com/wallet/ (or http://yourdomain.com/wallet/index/index/) it will only load this particular template file and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

The *.xml file which load your mywallet.phtml have called the header and footer so you cannot remove it from the phtml, you have to work on the corresponding xlm file.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Empty page layout, or in your xml file you use this:

```
<your_module_index translate="label">
    <reference name="root">
        <remove name="head" />
        <remove name="header" />
        <remove name="foooter" />
    </reffernce>
</your_module_index>
```

or even

```
<action method="setTemplate"><template>page/empty.phtml</template></action>
```